# Unable to find bundled Java version, after update android studio

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio

I have updated android studio, after that i am getting this error.
**Unable to find bundled Java version.**
[image]

Answer (score 3):

[unable to find bundle java version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yimcq.png)

for solving this error on mac just go to finder>Apllications>Android studio:

right click and click show package contents

open the folder of contents

create a new folder called jre

copy the contents of the jbr folder and paste them into jre folder

delete jbr folder

run flutter doctor your error is solved

Comment: If you want to clean up your answer,

Doing a symbolic link is better,

`cd "/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents";`

`ln -s jbr jre`

Answer (score 1):

The latest update of Android studio had an issue, which can be resolved as follows:
For Windows
Go To android studio directory (Default C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio)
remove jre folder
run cmd as administrator

```
cd C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
mklink /D "jre" "jbr"
```

This issue may be caused by the fact that newer version of Android Studio come with JBR as a bundled java version.For more Reference [click here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/106674#issuecomment-1381685888)

Answer (score 0):

Try restarting the Studio, reinstall it or Invalidate Caches from File. I am sure one of it will work. The package could be missing in the update. If it doesn't work, open a issue at [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new)

Comment: Try reinstalling

Answer (score 0):

If Just kidding's answer does not work you can just reinstall Android Studio (don't forget to load the Flutter and Dart plugins) and it should be fine again.

Comment: I'm almost try all possible solution but nothing work. Only this one work for me. Its from `August 9, 2021`

Check the link for the solution

https://stackoverflow.com/a/68703869/8555332

Answer (score 0):

My path to java was broken after updating AS to latest version (2020.3.1) and I had to fix it manually. Your issue seems related. Check your Android Studio -> Preferences -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Gradle and see if gradle jdk path is set correctly (to your java installation on your mac).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been fixed in the latest version of flutter 3.7.9